# Rails "AssociationTypeMismatch" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In attempts to test my models, im trying to run the following in rails console:

```
user.occasions << Occasion.first
```

getting this error:

```
irb(main):013:0>  user.occasions << Occasion.first
Occasion Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "occasions".* FROM "occasions" LIMIT 1
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Occasion(#70119208170580) expected, got NilClass(#70119200119960)`
```

Here are my model classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occasions
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :id
end

class Occasion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :name
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How can I get my code fragment to work?

Comment: Do you have any Occassions created? It seems to think `Occassion.first` is nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if either:

- You're attempting to add your first `Occasion` record to this `User` -- and there are no `Occasion` record yet created, or
- You're attempting to add the first `Occasion` record to this `User`, and that record already belongs to another `User`.

Can you try this in the console and post the results?

```
foo = Occasion.first
Occasion.first.inspect
```